# how to clone a jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, clone

Sirs,

In short, my question is "how do you clone a jTable in a GUI developed in Netbeans."

In a little more detail, I have a `jTabbedPane` that consists of two tabs - `myTab1` and `myTab2`.  Both tabs have a `jTable` that will display columns from a derby database.  Any time the data in the database is updated, I want both `jTables` to update to reflect the new information.  Essentially, the two `jTables` will show identical data in each cell, and any time a change is made to one there will be an automated change to the other.

Obviously, I could do this long-hand.  Any time a subroutine (that changes the data in the database) is executed, I could have an `UpdateMyTable1()` and an `UpdateMyTable2()` routine to make the changes.  However, in my case the `UpdateMyTable1()` function/method/subroutine would need to be a rather lengthy one, and `UpdateMyTable1()` would consist of almost identical code to `UpdateMyTable2()`.  There would be a lot of redundant code.

In Neatbeans, is there a way to instantiate (or otherwise create) two `jTables` in such a way that they always mirror each others contents without writing the code out long-hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't think about "cloning" but instead simply have both JTables share table model. Something as simple as

```
table1.setModel(table2.getModel());
```

could work.

If they share models, then changes in the model will be shown equally in both JTables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example of 'cloning' tables by model sharing. You can edit value by double-click on a cell. Changes are reflected in all tables.

You should set common model for all tables in your IDE and all data updates should operate on this common model.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CloningTablesExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CloningTablesExample::runApp);
    }

    static void runApp(){
        JTable original = new JTable(new Object[][]{
                {"v1", "v2"},
                {"v4", "v5"}
            },
            new String[]{"col1", "col2"}
        );

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        window.setSize(400, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(original));
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(cloneTable(original)));
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(cloneTable(original)));
    }

    private static JTable cloneTable(JTable original) {
        JTable clone = new JTable();
        clone.setModel(original.getModel());
        return clone;
    }
}
```