# How to create a copy of a JTable with same model, color, font and listeners?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, clone, java-17

I am making a program in which I need to use many JTables. So I need to clone a JTable many times. By cloning I mean a copy with same model, same columnModel, same font size, same color etc.

I have found [how to clone a jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798029/how-to-clone-a-jtable).

But the problem is only the text of the both is same. Not the font or colors.

I also tried this:-

```
JTable  t1 = new JTable(tm.getTable().getModel(), tm.getTable().getColumnModel());
```

But this is also not working.

I also tried:-

```
JTable ti = tm;
```

But this will work. But the problem is changes made to `tm` will also happen with `ti`.

Is there any way to clone a jtable with all its properties?

Comment: Rethink your software design. There must be code originally initializing these properties on the first table. Just extract that part to a reusable method which you can invoke a second time for the new `JTable` object.

Comment: @Holger Okay Sir.

Comment: Why would any GUI need many copies of (what sounds like) an identical table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```java
JTable  t1 = new JTable(tm.getTable().getModel(), tm.getTable().getColumnModel());
```

And then, take every **relevant** attribute that the first table has, and assign it to your second table.

For example:

```java
t1.setFont(tm.getFont());
// And so on
```

#### OR

You can always deep clone the object through serializing. Check [this](http://javatechniques.com/blog/low-memory-deep-copy-technique-for-java-objects/) article for more. It may be an overkill, but that is for you to decide.